# Using MATLAB API in C++, matOpen not working

Tags: c++, matlab, qt

I am writing a piece of code to access MATLAB files, my program compiles but crashes when I call `matOpen`. When I try to debug the code, the debugger also exits without reaching the offending line of code. I am working in Qt, and I am not too sure if I have done my includes properly.

.pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include"

LIBS += "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmx.lib"
LIBS += "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmat.lib"

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <mat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MATFile *mfPtr;
    const char *file = "data.mat";
    mfPtr = matOpen(file,"r"); //code runs successfully without this line
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using Desktop Qt 5.11.0 MSVC2017 64-bit and my MATLAB version is  2018a. I have also tried deleting the build folder and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
E:\CodePath>gcc *.c  -IC:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include -LC:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64 -o code -l libmat -l libmx
```

Place `libmat.dll` and `libmx.dll` in the CodePath

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work with the Matlab libraries either. For everyone looking for a different approach to write MAT files from C++, I recommend this open source project: https://github.com/jkriege2/TinyMAT

Comment: Please don’t post [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132403/7328782). Instead, flag the post as a duplicate.