# Using MATLAB API in C++, matOpen crashing program silently

Tags: c++, matlab, api, mat

my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902408/using-matlab-api-in-c-matopen-not-working) but it is rather old and I cannot comment or upvote due to my (beginners) reputation.
I am trying to compile the matcreat.cpp file from Matlab 2017b like this (using g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0):

```
g++ -c -o matcreat.o -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\extern\include" matcreat.cpp
g++ -o matcreat.exe matcreat.o -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmat -llibmex -llibmx -llibeng
```

The program has a main which uses printf right at the beginning (even before the matlab stuff), but nothing is put out and it just terminates. If I comment out all the MATLAB related function calls it works, the first one being `pmat = matOpen(file, "w");`.

Why is the program just silently crashing and outputting **nothing**? Why no compiler/linker errors? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try using the `mex` function to build your application. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html — There are a lot of compiler switches and preprocessor definitions to get right, the `mex` function does this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying to work around the internals of the `mex` building process I gave up on that route. Mathworks is deliberately trying to make it hard to incorporate their features into your own code.

For everyone with the same problems: After some research I found [this open source project](https://github.com/jkriege2/TinyMAT), which can write MAT files just fine.